# How to avoid `invalid access of mutable storage in an 'isolated' function`?

Tags: ballerina, isolation

I have an abstract type which is being used in few concrete objects and a record type that contains a list of that abstract type.

```php
public type AbstractType object {
    isolated function profile() returns string;
};

public isolated class ConcreteImpl1 {
    *AbstractType;
    isolated function profile() returns string {
        return "concreteOne";
    }
}
public isolated class ConcreteImpl2 {
    *AbstractType;
    isolated function profile() returns string {
        return "concreteTwo";
    }
}

public type ImplHolderType record {
    AbstractType[] implementations;
};
```

I have initialized `ImplHolderType` with 2 objects and trying to access one of the values inside an isolated function.

```
final ImplHolderType implList = {
    implementations: [new ConcreteImpl1(), new ConcreteImpl2()]
};

isolated resource function get sample/profile() returns string {
        AbstractType abstractType = implList.implementations[0];
        return abstractType.profile();
}
```

Here I'm getting an error when I'm trying to access the list (`implList.implementations[0]`) saying `invalid access of mutable storage`.
Can you suggest a workaround that I can do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `implList` is mutable (even though it is final, the fields can still be updated), you can't access it within an isolated function. You could make `implList` an isolated variable and then access it within the isolated function. You'll have to use a lock statement when accessing.

```php
isolated ImplHolderType implList = {
    implementations: [new ConcreteImpl1(), new ConcreteImpl2()]
};

service on new http:Listener(8080) {
    isolated resource function get sample/profile() returns string {
        lock {
            return implList.implementations[0].profile();
        }
    }
}
```

https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/isolated-variables

https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/#concurrency-safety

Alternatively, if your implementation classes won't have any mutable fields, you can make them `readonly` classes, and then make `implList` be of type `readonly & ImplHolderType`, which will make it be immutable. Then you would be able to access it in an isolated function without a lock statement.

```php
import ballerina/http;

public type AbstractType object {
    isolated function profile() returns string;
};

public readonly class ConcreteImpl1 {
    *AbstractType;
    isolated function profile() returns string {
        return "concreteOne";
    }
}

public readonly class ConcreteImpl2 {
    *AbstractType;
    isolated function profile() returns string {
        return "concreteTwo";
    }
}

public type ImplHolderType record {
    AbstractType[] implementations;
};

final readonly & ImplHolderType implList = {
    implementations: [new ConcreteImpl1(), new ConcreteImpl2()]
};

service on new http:Listener(8080) {
    isolated resource function get sample/profile() returns string {
        return implList.implementations[0].profile();
    }
}
```